# How to optimize dataframe iteration in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to iterate a dataframe, for each row I need to create a ID based on two existing columns: name and sex. Eventually I add this new column to the df.

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', dtype=str, na_values="", low_memory=False)
   row_ids = []
   for index, row in df.iterrows():
       if (index % 1000) == 0:
          print("Row node index: {}".format(str(index)))
     
     caculated_id = get_id(row['name', row['sex']])
     row_ids.append(caculated_id)

   df['id'] = row_ids
```

Is there a way to make it much faster without going row by row?

Add more info based on suggested solutions:

Comment: Could you include the function `get_id` and a sample of the df?

Comment: It is a regular function, taking input and return anything. Just for example purpose.

Comment: How is the id constructed? Include a small sample dataframe. I'm not sure what  `get_id(row['name', row['sex']])` is supposed to do.

Comment: id=hash(name+sex)

Comment: @marlon - pandas lets you perform operations in bulk. Suppose `id` is just the concatenation of `name` and `sex`. You could do `df['id'] = df['name'] + df['sex']`. Instead of a function that does something to indvidual cells, see if you can do things with entire columns.

Comment: Using pandas operators and functions is usually much faster than applying a function per row.

Comment: df['id'] = df['name'] + df['sex']: need apply a hash function, not raw string

Comment: AFAIK, not much you can do with *built-in functions* to speed up string operations. `.iterrows` is usually slower than vanilla `for` loop, which is about the same as `.apply` and `np.vectorize`. Difference, if any is not significant.

Comment: So `df['id'] = [get_id[x,y] for x,y in zip(df['name'], df['sex'])]` is rather fast and sort, albeit the logging...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working on a large dataset then `np.vectorize()` should help bypass the `apply()` overhead, which should be a bit faster.

```
import numpy as np

v = np.vectorize(lambda x: get_id(x['name'], x['sex']))
df['id'] = v(df)
```

**Edit:**

To get even more of a speed up you could also just pass the function `get_id` instead of using a lambda function and pass `df.*.values` instead of `df.*`.

```
v = np.vectorize(get_id)
df['id'] = v(df['name'].values, df['sex'].values)
```

Instead of printing updates about the progression through the process try using `tqdm` to show the progression using a progress bar.

```
import numpy as np 
from tqdm import tqdm

@np.vectorize
def get_id(name, sex):
    global pbar
    ...
    pbar.update(1)
    ...
    return 


global pbar
with tqdm(total=len(df)) as pbar:
    df['id'] = get_id(df['name'].values, df['sex'].values)
```

Comment: If get_id returns multiple lists, v{df} is of list of list? get_id could be renamed as get_new_columns.

Comment: @marlon yes it should, it basically works the same as `apply()`.  Please do try it out and let me know if its faster for you.

Comment: i will try for speed.

Comment: In your code, is 'df' missing in the 2nd line?

Comment: @marlon no it doesn't need the `df` to be passed in `v`. Also I added in an improvement could you check if it works?

Comment: This looks nice. I edited my code: originally, i also have a print() statement in the loop. Then in get_id, how to pass the index parameter into it? There is no index anymore, but log the progress is very useful.

Comment: Hmm instead of printing I think you could use `tqdm` to just log the progression through the entire loop, but let me check how to do it. I think you could setup a global value that gets updated in the `get_id` then pass that to `get_id`.

Comment: @marlon I have updated the answer to show a progress bar instead of printing the progress. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Please continue to see my real question, which has more difficulties. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69431717/how-to-optimize-dataframe-iteration-for-complex-row-operation-inside-the-loop

Answer (score 2):

Use `apply` instead:

```
def func(x):
    if (x.name % 1000) == 0:
        print("Row node index: {}".format(str(x.name)))
 
    caculated_id = get_id(row['name', row['sex']])
    return caculated_id

df['id'] = df.apply(func, axis=1)
```

Comment: Does the apply here returns a list of new ids?

Comment: @marlon Yes. Of course.

Comment: I will test the speed on a big csv file.

Comment: If my get_xxx() function returns multiple lists for more general cases, it should also work?

Comment: @marlon Yes, `apply` returns a series of all the results.

Comment: I edited my code: originally, i also have a print() statement in the loop. Then in get_id, how to pass the index parameter into it? There is no index anymore.

Comment: @marlon Edited mine

Comment: Please check: row['name', row['sex']]. Is this correct?

Comment: @marlon should be `x['name'], x['sex']`

Comment: x.name % 1000: what does the 'name' mean here?